# Advice on how to remove these weird black shadow things?

Tags: modeling

I am not sure what to do with these vertices to fix this weird pinch I have. It creates weird shadows and looks bad. Here are some images.

[image: Top pinch view]

[image: vertices faces look different sizes]

I could probably just delete a big chunk and try again but maybe this will be a good learning experience for the future to learn other ways to fix this. Thanks a lot for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a Face/Polygon inside the handle, deleting that face will fix the shading problem.

Answer (score 0):

The pinch looks like what Josip  said, but the shading looks more like flipped normals. Select all vertices in edit mode and hit Ctrl-N to recalculate the normals.